# Docker containers starts at different subtnets

Tags: wordpress, networking, nginx, docker

I have to start up 3 containers, nginx, wordpress and wordpress2. The problem is the nginx container starts at 172.17.0.2, wordpress at 172.18.0.3 and wordpress2 at 172.19.0.4.
The wordpress containers starts with their docker-compose.yml configured as i show:

For wordpress:

```
version: '2'
services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - "./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     links:
       - db
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     networks:
       - ipv4_address: 172.17.0.5
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
```

For wordpress2:

```
version: '2'
    services:
       db:
         image: mysql:5.7
         volumes:
           - "./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
         restart: always
         environment:
           MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
           MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
           MYSQL_USER: wordpress
           MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     links:
       - db
     ports:
       - "8001:80"
     networks:
       - ipv4_address: 172.17.0.6
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
```

As you can see, i put at networks field the ipv4_address but when i start up the docker-compose.yml it shows error at this line. I thought that by default, all containers usually stars at same network but not in this case. Can you help me to put all containers at same subnet?

Comment: If all 3 containers are part of the same stack, would it be possible for you to put them all in the same docker-compose file? If you can, you can use docker's built in dns to access containers by their host name and you won't have to care about specific IP addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each docker-compose.yml will create it's own subnet. So your 3 containers can't *see* each other. 
Networks created by other docker-compose are said to be *external* so you have to declare them as such. You can see these networks using `docker network ls`.

After declaring the external networks in your external networks in your docker-compose.yml file, you will have to define what networks should be using by the *nginx* service. You should keep the `default` network.

Usually the default name for your docker-compose network is `<current_dir>_default`. So suppose your current directory is called *yourproject1* the network name is going to be `yourproject1_default`.

And then you will be able to access your wordpress containers using [`external_links`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#externallinks) (better than ip addresses IMO)

Here what I would do for nginx's docker-compose.yml file to make him able to see wordpress containers :

```
version: '2'

services:
  nginx:
    ...
    external_links:
      - your_project1_wordpress1_1:wordpress1
      - your_other_project2_wordpress2_1:wordpress2
    networks:
      - default
      - your_project1_default
      - your_other_project2_defaul



networks:
  your_project1_default:
    external: true
  your_other_project2_default:
    external: true
```

Comment: @Asier I'm glad it did help. You can mark the answer as correct (http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png) to better help the community.